# Linux : System.DllNotFoundException: UnityInterface2.dll

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, kinect, openni, xbox360

I am trying to run the asset imported from 
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10693

It works fine in windows , but I get below error in Linux  at below code

```
.....code start.......
[DllImport("UnityInterface2.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int Init(bool isInitDepthStream, bool isInitColorStream, bool isInitInfraredStream);
.......code end........

...error....
System.DllNotFoundException: UnityInterface2.dll
at (wrapper managed-to-native) KinectWrapper:Init (bool,bool,bool)
at KinectManager.Start () [0x00000] in /home/ashok/New Unity Project/Assets/KinectScripts/KinectManager.cs:657
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
KinectManager:Start() (at Assets/KinectScripts/KinectManager.cs:808)
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux is not supported. It was not built to work on Linux. The plugin only supports Windows and Mac. That's it. Even when you look on the Store, it says the plugin is for Windows and Mac. Linux was never mentioned anywhere.

Comment: I am trying to implement in Linux. What changes need to be done so that it works in Linux ?

Comment: Basically need to create UnityInterface.so file instead of UnityInterface.dll by compiling the files present in https://github.com/rfilkov/OpenNi2UnityInterface but unable to compile it .The below link conatains the issue faced https://github.com/rfilkov/OpenNi2UnityInterface/issues/1 .Could you pls hepl resolve the issue

Comment: @B.M.Ashok No dude.I program in C++ but have never compiled for Linux. I don't even have Linux to begin with. My goal is to tell you the problem and tell you what to do to fix it. Linux is simply not supported and if you find a way to build it for Linux, it should work.